# Component doesn't re-render on state change Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I have QuestionFeed component which basically renders questions with infinite scrolling. However, I have NavTopicFilter (also serves as provider of context API ) component within Navbar component to list dropdown menu of topics. The plan is when a user select a topic, QuestionFeed would query questions with the given topic.  I can see the selected topic in QuestionFeed component immediately, however, it doesn't re-render or make query. Instead after selecting a topic, when I click another tab or anywhere outside the app and then click app tab again, it updates. I am beginner and struggling to figure out why.

```
 "use client";
import { ExtendedQuestion } from "@/types/db";
import { useIntersection } from "@mantine/hooks";
import { useInfiniteQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { INFINITE_SCROLL_PAGINATION_RESULTS } from "@/config/config";
import QuestionCard from "./QuestionCard";
import { useFilter } from "../FilterContext";

interface QuestionFeedProps {
  initialQuestions: ExtendedQuestion[];
  topicName?: string;
}

const QuestionFeed: FC<QuestionFeedProps> = ({
  initialQuestions,
  topicName,
}) => {
  const lastPostRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const { ref, entry } = useIntersection({
    root: lastPostRef.current,
    threshold: 1,
  });

  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const { selectedTopic } = useFilter();

  console.log("From feed");

  const { data, fetchNextPage, isFetchingNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ["infinite-query"],
    async ({ pageParam = 1 }) => {
      const query = `/api/q/?limit=${INFINITE_SCROLL_PAGINATION_RESULTS}&page=${pageParam}&topicId=${selectedTopic}`;

      const { data } = await axios.get(query);
      return data as ExtendedQuestion[];
    },

    {
      getNextPageParam: (_, pages) => {
        return pages.length + 1;
      },
      initialData: { pages: [initialQuestions], pageParams: [1] },
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (entry?.isIntersecting) {
      fetchNextPage(); // Load more posts when the last post comes into view
    }
  }, [entry, fetchNextPage]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNextPage();
  }, [selectedTopic]);

  const questions = data?.pages.flatMap((page) => page) ?? initialQuestions;

  return (
    <ul className="flex flex-col col-span-2 space-y-2">
      <p>Selected Filter: {selectedTopic}</p>
      {questions?.map((question, index) => {
        const votesAmt = question.votes.reduce((acc, vote) => {
          if (vote.type === "UP") return acc + 1;
          if (vote.type === "DOWN") return acc - 1;
          return acc;
        }, 0);

        const currentVote = question.votes.find(
          // @ts-ignore
          (vote) => vote.userId === session?.user?.id
        );

        if (index === questions.length - 1) {
          // Add a ref to the last post in the list

          return (
            <li key={question.id} ref={ref}>
              <QuestionCard
                content={question.content}
                answerAmt={question._count?.answers}
                topicName={question?.topic?.name}
                votesAmt={votesAmt}
                currentVote={currentVote}
                key={question?.id}
                questionId={question.id}
                authorId={question.authorId}
                authorName={question.author?.username ?? ""}
                authorImage={question.author.image ?? ""}
                createdAt={question.createdAt}
              />
            </li>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <QuestionCard
              content={question.content}
              answerAmt={question._count?.answers}
              topicName={question?.topic?.name}
              votesAmt={votesAmt}
              currentVote={currentVote}
              key={question?.id}
              questionId={question.id}
              authorImage={question.author.image ?? ""}
              authorId={question.authorId}
              authorName={question.author?.username ?? ""}
              createdAt={question.createdAt}
            />
          );
        }
      })}

      {isFetchingNextPage && (
        <li className="flex justify-center">
          <Loader2 className="w-6 h-6 text-zinc-500 animate-spin" />
        </li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default QuestionFeed;
```

**From FilterContext.tsx**

```
// FilterContext.tsx
"use client"
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode } from 'react';

interface FilterContextProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface FilterContextValue {
  selectedTopic: string;
  handleFilterChange: (filter: string) => void;
}

const FilterContext = createContext<FilterContextValue | undefined>(undefined);

export const FilterProvider: React.FC<FilterContextProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [selectedTopic, setSelectedTopic] = useState('');

  const handleFilterChange = (filter: string) => {
    setSelectedTopic(filter);
  };

  return (
    <FilterContext.Provider value={{ selectedTopic, handleFilterChange }}>
      {children}
    </FilterContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFilter = (): FilterContextValue => {
  const context = useContext(FilterContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useFilter must be used within a FilterProvider');
  }
  return context;
};
```

**NavTopicFilter.tsx**

```
"use client";

import {
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownMenuContent,
  DropdownMenuItem,
  DropdownMenuSeparator,
  DropdownMenuTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/DropdownMenu";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "sonner";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { Topic } from "@prisma/client";
import { Icons } from "./Icons";
import { useFilter } from "./FilterContext";

interface NavTopicFilterProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {}

export function NavTopicFilter({}: NavTopicFilterProps) {
  const { selectedTopic, handleFilterChange } = useFilter();


  async function fetchPosts() {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get(`/api/topic`);
      return resp.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error fetching posts:", err); // Log the error for debugging
      toast.error("Something went wrong");
      throw err; // Rethrow the error to propagate it further if needed
    }
  }

  const query = useQuery(["topics"], fetchPosts);

  /*   const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("አጠቃላይ"); // Default selected option
   */ if (query.isLoading) {
    // Handle loading state if needed
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownMenuTrigger>
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-1 hover:bg-zinc-100 font-bold">
          <div className="pl-2 md:pl-3 text-white flex flex-row">
            <span className="md:text-black sm:text-white">ርእስ</span>
            <Icons.filter className="h-6 w-6 md:text-black sm:text-white" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </DropdownMenuTrigger>
      <DropdownMenuContent className="bg-white" align="end">
        {query.data?.map((option: Topic) => (
          <DropdownMenuItem
            asChild
            className="cursor-pointer"
            onSelect={(event) => {
              event.preventDefault();
              handleFilterChange(option.id);
            }}
            key={option.id}
          >
            <option value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
          </DropdownMenuItem>
        ))}
      </DropdownMenuContent>
    </DropdownMenu>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can  you share useFilter() code?

Comment: @Anshu I updated the question (added the FilterContext snippet). If you see the QuestionFeed, I put <p>Selected Filter: {selectedTopic}</p> to see if selected topic updates correctly.

Comment: Are you calling `handleFilterChange` anywhere to update the state?

Comment: @DustInComp He is selecting from Navbar where handleFilterChange will change the selecteTopic. I am struggling to find issue. I may need to see the Navbar handling selectedTopic state.

Comment: It changes at NavTopicFitler, dropdown menu to select top.ic (just posted).

Comment: @DustInComp,@Anshu I posted NavTopicFilter snippet if you want check it but I think the filer works like expected. Its value is also reflected in QuestionFeed.